# Creating a Dataframe with special special format

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

What is the best approach to create a Dataframe for the next conditions?

I have a Dataframe with a single column, there are several Families and below each Family there are some Description of items, some families have 3 items some of them have 7, the only cue to identify the families is by the "[online]" string.

```
0 Family Item1[online]
1 Description of the Item1 (SKU)
2 Description of the Item1 (SKU)
3 Description of the Item1 (SKU)
4 Family Item2[online]
5 Description of the Item2 (SKU)
6 Description of the Item2 (SKU)
7 Description of the Item2 (SKU)
................................
n-3Family Itemk[online]
n-2 Description of the Itemk (SKU)
n-1 Description of the Itemk (SKU)
n Description of the Itemk (SKU)
```

and I would like to get a dataframe with 2 columns

```
Column1 Column2
0  Family Item1  Description Item1
1  Family Item1  Description Item1
2  Family Item1  Description Item1
3  Family Item2  Description Item2
..................................
n Family Itemk Description Itemk
```

So I have the cue of [online] to identify the Family Items and each Family has a different number of Items.

What is the more pythonic way to solve this?.

Comment: Could you please clarify, what is your input data? Is it Python list, or a file, or what? What are "Description of the Item1 (SKU)"? Simple example of input and desired output data will be much appreciated.

Comment: It is a Dataframe with just one column

Comment: You've left too many unanswered questions.  Are families always grouped by Four, one family item followed by 3 descriptions? If not, is the word `"Family"` actually the word that is in the real data?  Meaning, can we write code that searches for the word `'Family'`?  Or are you going to say, "oh that won't work because you see, my data actually looks like this other thing I didn't bring up til now."  You see where I'm going?   This is too vague.

Comment: ok I would try to be more specific, let me edit, cheers

Comment: You might be better off turning each Family Item into a pandas Series and then concatenating the series into a DataFrame using pandas concat. This should make it possible for you to handle family items of varying lengths without a problem.

Comment: Returning back to @IlyaV.Schurov's important question since your data frame is not really structured properly in two dimensions for proper analysis. How was it originally created? Please advise if it derived from a text/xml/json file, database, web page, python list/dictionary/series.

Comment: It was created from a txt file. so I used read_csv('path', delimiter = '\n', header = None)

Answer (score 0):

Given your initial dataframe looks like this:

```
import pandas as pd

df = pd.DataFrame(data=['Family Item1[online]',
                        'Description of the Item1 (SKU)',
                        'Description of the Item1 (SKU)',
                        'Description of the Item1 (SKU)',
                        'Family Item2[online]',
                        'Description of the Item2 (SKU)',
                        'Description of the Item2 (SKU)',
                        'Description of the Item2 (SKU)',],index=np.arange(0,8))

dict_i = {}
key = None

for item in df[0].values:

    if '[online]' in item:
        key = item
        dict_i[key] = []
    else:
        dict_i[key].append(item)
pd.DataFrame(dict_i)
```

Which gives:

```
             Family Item1[online]            Family Item2[online]
0  Description of the Item1 (SKU)  Description of the Item2 (SKU)
1  Description of the Item1 (SKU)  Description of the Item2 (SKU)
2  Description of the Item1 (SKU)  Description of the Item2 (SKU)
```

And if the series are not the same lengths:

```
series_list = []
for k, v in dict_i.items():
    s = pd.Series(data=v,name=k)
    series_list.append(s)

pd.concat(series_list,axis=1)
```

Which results in a dataframe with missing values whre the lengths do not match.

```
             Family Item1[online]            Family Item2[online]
0  Description of the Item1 (SKU)  Description of the Item2 (SKU)
1  Description of the Item1 (SKU)  Description of the Item2 (SKU)
2  Description of the Item1 (SKU)  Description of the Item2 (SKU)
3  Description of the Item1 (SKU)                             NaN
4  Description of the Item1 (SKU)                             NaN
```